# What kind of documentation do I need to fly alone within Europe, when under 18?

Tags: air-travel, paperwork, netherlands, minors, denmark

To fly alone from Denmark to the Netherlands, without any transfers, what kind of documentation, signature from parents or any other kind of paper does an under 18-year-old person need?

Comment: What is the actual age? And not sure if that matters, but also which airline?

Comment: @mts 16, and it will most likely be 'Transavia',

Comment: You would need a notarized writing from your parents saying that they allow you to travel alone. You might need to contact the airline as well, but I don't think it is really necessary.

Comment: @MertKarakaya Do you have a source for that? Many countries don't "do" notarisation - eg in the UK important documents are witnessed rather than notarised - so I'd be surprised if there's a blanket requirement for something that's only used in some countries

Comment: @Gagravarr There are notaries in UK (http://www.thenotariessociety.org.uk/what-is-a-notary) which do authorization for the documents with intended use "abroad". My source is personal experience. To travel to Austria alone (with dual citizenship Romania and Turkey), they require you to have notarized permission document stating the flight details and the person taking care of the minor in the arrival country.

Comment: There certainly are, but they're rather expensive, and only really deal with people trying to fill in official forms for other countries. Given that one of the points of EU rules is to harmonise things between countries with different systems, I very much doubt there will be a hard requirement for something only found/used in a subset of the EU member states.

Comment: My kids flew a occasionally alone when they were underage, mostly transatlantic. The never had a problem and no special paperwork was required.  I recommend checking with the airline to make sure. EDIT: Lufthansa will allow kids to fly alone age 12 and up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your principal concern will be with the airline.  They can impose a variety of requirements, but these can vary from company to company.  You can generally find information on the company's web site, or, presumably, by calling the company's customer service office.

Transavia appears to have no special documentary requirements.  For children from age 5 to age 11, unaccompanied children must pay for and use the unaccompanied minor service; from age 12 to age 15, this service is optional.  For sixteen and seventeen year olds, therefore, we can infer that the service is unavailable.

You are probably also wondering about legal requirements imposed by the countries you'll be traveling in.  There appears to be no definite requirement in international, EU, or Dutch law.

For example, from http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/eu-citizen/index_en.htm:

> **Documents for minors**
>
> In addition to their own valid passport or ID card, all children travelling:
>
> - alone; or
> - with adults who are not their legal guardian; or
> - with only one parent
>
> may need an extra (official) document signed by their parents, second parent or legal guardian(s) authorising them to travel.
>
> There are no EU rules on this matter, each EU country decides whether or not it requires such documents. Check, before the child travels, the requirements of the country you are travelling both from and to:

Here follows a "choose country" link that allows you to check the requirements for various European countries.  This is followed by a disclaimer and some additional information:

> The European Commission is not responsible for the content of external websites
>
> Bear in mind that, even where a country does not require minors to carry such an authorisation to leave or enter its territory, other countries they transit through may still ask them to show one.
>
> When travelling by air it is highly recommended that you check with the airlines beforehand as many require such authorisations and have their own specific forms for this purpose.
>
> As each country's rules may change without notice you are also encouraged to check with the authorities themselves or with the respective embassies or consulates.

It is definitely a good idea to follow the above advice.

Using the "choose country" link for Denmark, we find

> Other than their own valid travel document (passport or ID card), no particular extra official document is required authorising minors of any EU country to enter or leave Denmark.

For the Netherlands (omitting some text irrelevant to your case):

> Other than their own valid travel document (passport or ID card), no particular extra official authorisation is required for minors of any EU country to enter or leave the Netherlands.

Finally, although it appears not to be *required,* it would not hurt anything to carry a letter signed by your parents or guardians stating that you are traveling with their permission.  You could bring a photocopy of their passports or ID documents to support the authenticity of the letter.  You would also want a copy of the document showing their relationship to you.  This would normally be your birth certificate, but if they are adoptive parents or court-appointed guardians, it would be the adoption papers or a court order or the like.